# ReactJS - Same method, different results

Tags: reactjs, methods, clarifai

I'm learning React and, while following a tutorial I wonder why the #1 method doesn't console.log anything, while the #2 one does.
Can someone please explain why is that?

```
calculateFaceLocation = (data) => {
  return (console.log(data.outputs[0].data.regions[0].region_info.bounding_box));
}

//DOESN'T WORK
onButtonSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({imageUrl: this.state.input})
    app.models.predict(Clarifai.FACE_DETECT_MODEL, this.state.input).then(
      function (response) {
        this.calculateFaceLocation(response);
      }
    )
      }

//WORKS
onButtonSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({imageUrl: this.state.input})
    app.models.predict(Clarifai.FACE_DETECT_MODEL, this.state.input).then(response => this.calculateFaceLocation(response)).catch(err=> console.log(err));
      }
```

Comment: Okay... thank you. I thought that the function would be called by the (), while receiving the response parameter. What would be the correct way to address this? I'm confused

Answer (score 0):

In the #1 function, you give one regular function to .then(), so when it calls

```js
this.calculateFaceLocation(response);
```

`this` object does not have that calculateFaceLocation() method which defines inside your react class, instead `this` object contains the window object.

But for your #2 function, you are using the arrow function which is why you are getting your console log value here. Because in the arrow function it does not have it's own `this` instead it's getting it from the parent.

Read more about [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

I have added `console.log(this);` inside both functions. Now run this code and check the console you will see the difference.

```js
calculateFaceLocation = (data) => {
    return (console.log(data.outputs[0].data.regions[0].region_info.bounding_box));
}

//DOESN'T WORK
onButtonSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({ imageUrl: this.state.input })
    app.models.predict(Clarifai.FACE_DETECT_MODEL, this.state.input).then(
        function (response) {
            console.log(this);
            this.calculateFaceLocation(response);
        }
    )
}

//WORKS
onButtonSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({ imageUrl: this.state.input })
    app.models.predict(Clarifai.FACE_DETECT_MODEL, this.state.input).then(
        response => {
            console.log(this);
            this.calculateFaceLocation(response);            
        }
        ).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```